# Can't visualize Pose in Rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to implement a path planning algorithm on a static image.
I have obtained an occupancy grid and have also published a point via geometry_msgs/PoseStamped, but i cannot visualize this on Rviz .

This is the publisher that Ive written

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('move_base_simple/goal',PoseStamped,queue_size=1)
rospy.init_node('pose_publisher',anonymous = True)
rate = rospy.Rate(1)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    p = PoseStamped()
    p.header.seq = 1
    p.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    p.header.frame_id = 'map'
    p.pose.position.x = 100
    p.pose.position.y = 100
    p.pose.position.z = 0
    p.pose.orientation.x = 0
    p.pose.orientation.x = 0
    p.pose.orientation.x = 0
    p.pose.orientation.w = 1
    pub.publish(p)
    rate.sleep()
```

What am i doing wrong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339418/can%27t-visualize-pose-in-rviz/) by [TenderTadpole7](https://answers.ros.org/users/50013/tendertadpole7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After increasing the scale of the pose arrow i was able to vizualise it

---

Originally posted by [TenderTadpole7](https://answers.ros.org/users/50013/tendertadpole7/) with karma: 26 on 2019-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-08**:
Seems you've already figured it out, but just the draw some attention to it:

> ```
> p.pose.position.x = 100
> ```

```
p.pose.position.y = 100
```

This places the `PoseStamped` at 100 metres in the X direction and 100 metres in the Y direction.

While of course perfectly valid, it is quite a distance.

**Comment by [TenderTadpole7](https://answers.ros.org/users/50013/tendertadpole7/) on 2019-12-08**:
Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I hadn't noticed that this was in meters

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-08**:
As everything in ROS, `PoseStamped` uses SI units. See also [REP-103: Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#units).

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-08-01**:
@gvdhoorn If the `frame_id` is set to `map`, shouldn't `p.pose.position.x` and `p.pose.position.y` represent the co-ordinates `(x,y)` in the `map` frame rather than `(x metres, y metres)` in the `map` frame? In case we want to represent a point `(x,y)` in the `map` frame, we need to set the `p.pose.position.x` and `p.pose.position.y` as `x*resolution` and `y * resolution` respectively?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-01**:
No. ROS uses metres for distances. How would a pose publisher know the resolution of your map? Or any other map? Making poses resolution dependent would immediately complicate software reuse, as suddenly everyone would need to take map resolution into account.